Unity stuck on reloading domain after importing Windows project on macOS
I'm facing a persistent issue where Unity gets stuck on “reloading domain” whenever I open a project on macOS that was previously developed on a Windows PC. This happens for all projects cloned from a Windows environment, across multiple Unity versions (2021, 2022, 2023, and 6). However, projects created from scratch on macOS work without issues.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know any possible fixes? This issue seems to only happen when working with projects that were initially opened on a Windows PC, but projects made directly on macOS don't have this problem. I've tried everything I can think of, but it still persists.
Steps I've taken to troubleshoot:

Reinstalled Unity and Unity Hub multiple times.
Completely reinstalled macOS (currently using Sonoma, but I also tried the Sequoia beta. When it didn't work, I reverted back to Sonoma).
Disabled domain reloading from Player Settings. While this allows me to enter play mode without getting stuck, the issue arises again when I make any script changes and save. At that point, the editor freezes on “reloading domain” after saving the modified script.


is there anything in the log files?

How exactly did you transfer that? Have you tried to delete the Library and other temporary or adhoc generated folders and let Unity reimport everything from scratch?

One up for Hugo's suggestion. I haven't used Mac but Library folder is not meant to be propagated. Everything in there is regenerated and only meant for caching. Since we are talking about moving a project from one OS to another, I also recommend deleting Library and regenerating everything.

Tried deleting it, but the same thing happened it got stuck on reloading.
